# word 2007: adding form fields

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-word

does anyone know how to add a TEXTBOX onto a word 2007 document. i need to gather user input and after the form is filled out, the data will be added into an access database

thank you!

Comment: Which version of Word and which file format are you using?

Comment: 2007 please help with also form restriction , maybe you can send some links about building word forms with access backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word supports different kind of text input fields:

- "legacy" input fields that are implemented using Word fields:

  ```
  Selection.FormFields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:= wdFieldFormTextInput
  ```
- ActiveX controls:

  ```
  Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEControl ClassType:="Forms.TextBox.1"
  ```
- Content controls (Word 2007 or later):

  ```
  Selection.Range.ContentControls.Add (wdContentControlText)
  ```

Comment: thanks! now maybe you can answer this q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321449/adodb-connection-to-accdb-file