# ADODB connection to ACCDB file -- unrecognized database format error

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a file like this:

```
strPath = "S:\HR\Forms\forms_database.accdb"
```

I am connecting to it through an WORD `adodb.connection`

should my database be a different extension ? MDB or something?

I am getting this error when it tries to connect:

```
unrecognized database format 's:...............accdb'
```

what's going on here?

here's the entire code:

```
Sub TransferShipper()

  'Transfer new shipping company record to

  'Shippers table in Northwind database.

  Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
  Dim strConnection As String
  Dim strSQL As String
  Dim strPath As String
  Dim doc As Word.Document
  Dim strCompanyName As String
  Dim strPhone As String
  Dim bytContinue As Byte
  Dim lngSuccess As Long
  Set doc = ThisDocument
  On Error GoTo ErrHandler

  strCompanyName = Chr(39) & doc.FormFields("txtCompanyName").Result & Chr(39)
  strPhone = Chr(39) & doc.FormFields("txtPhone").Result & Chr(39)
  'Confirm new record.
  bytContinue = MsgBox("Do you want to insert this record?", vbYesNo, "Add Record")
  Debug.Print bytContinue
  'Process input values.
  If bytContinue = vbYes Then
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO vacation " _
     & "(title, department) " _
     & "VALUES (" _
     & strCompanyName & ", " _
     & strPhone & ")"
    Debug.Print strSQL
    'Substitute path and connection string with DSN if available.
    strPath = "S:\HR\Forms\forms_database.accdb"
    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" _
     & "Data Source = " & strPath
    Debug.Print strConnection
    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    cnn.Open strConnection
    cnn.Execute strSQL, lngSuccess
    cnn.Close
    MsgBox "You inserted " & lngSuccess & " record", _
     vbOKOnly, "Error Added"
    doc.FormFields("txtCompanyName").TextInput.Clear
    doc.FormFields("txtPhone").TextInput.Clear
  End If
  Set doc = Nothing
  Set cnn = Nothing
  Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, _
   vbOKOnly, "Error"
  On Error GoTo 0
  On Error Resume Next
  cnn.Close
  Set doc = Nothing
  Set cnn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try ACE OLEDB 12.0 as the db version.

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
```